# Eigenvector shared by two endomorhisms

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am guessing if the following fact is true:
Let be $V$ a finite vector space above a field $K$.
Let $f, g$ be two endomorphisms of $V$ with $f g = g f$. 
We assume that both $f$ and $g$ have got at least one eigenvector.
Then $f$ and $g$ have got one eigenvector in common.
I have proved for a 2-dimensional vectorial space. Do you think that this is always true? Is it a known fact?

Answer (score 1):

First we prove that since $f$ and $g$ commute and if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f$  then the associated eigenspace $E_\lambda (f)=\ker(f-\lambda\operatorname{id})$ is invariant by $g$: in fact, if $x\in E_\lambda(f)$ then $f(x)=\lambda x$ so 
$$f(g(x))=g(f(x))=g(\lambda x)=\lambda g(x)$$
and then $g(x)\in E_\lambda (f)$. Now let $g_1$ the restriction of $g$ on $E_\lambda(f)$ and let $v$ an eigenvector of $g_1$ associated to an eigenvalue $\mu$ of $g_1$ then clearly $v$ is a common eigenvector of $f$ and $g$.

**Remark** This result depends on the field $\Bbb K$ since the eigenvalues $\lambda$ or $\mu$ may not exist but the result is obviously true if $\Bbb K=\Bbb C$.

Comment: So the fact may be not true for every dimension and depends on the field, right?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: In particular, for $V = \mathbb{R}^3$, do you think it is always true?

Comment: Yes it's true. We know by the intermediate theorem that for a polynomial with real coefficients and odd degree there's certainly a real root.

Comment: Right! So in order to find a contra example we must consider $\mathbb{R}^4$. I cannot find an explicit couple of endomorphism that satisfy the ipotesis but not the thesis. Can you find them?

Comment: In $\Bbb R^4$ take this matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
which hasn't a real eigenvalue.

Comment: "We assume that both and have got at least one eigenvector"